# Symfony2 listener class not loading?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am struggling with something that may sound stupid but :

I created a listener class that add content to Lucene Search Index after an entity is persisted.

My config.yml :

```
services:
searchindexer.listener:
    class: ripr\WfBundle\Listener\SearchIndexer
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

My file is in src/ripr/WfBundle/Listener

Filename is SearchIndexer.php

Class name is SearchIndexer

Namespace is ripr\WfBundle\Listener

I get an error on this line

```
$index = $this->get('ivory_lucene_search')->getIndex('identifier1');
```

error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

This sounds to me that class is not loaded. I can't get where I am wrong.

I flush dev cache multiples times.

This precise line works perfectly when I call it inside a classic Controller.

--------Edited--------

My class code to help

```
 <?php

namespace ripr\WfBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use ripr\WfBundle\Entity\Item;
use Ivory\LuceneSearchBundle\Model\Document;
use Ivory\LuceneSearchBundle\Model\Field;

/**
 * Search indexer.
 *
 * 
 */

class SearchIndexer extends Controller
 {

    /**
     * Index content
     *
     */
    public function postPersist (LifeCycleEventArgs $args) {

        //  $luceneSearch = $this->get('ivory_lucene_search');
        //  $luceneSearch->eraseIndex('identifier1');

            $entity = $args->getEntity();
            $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

            // perhaps you only want to act on some "Product" entity


                $index = $this->get('ivory_lucene_search')->getIndex('identifier1');
                $document = new Document();
                $document->addField(Field::text('titre', 'bille'));
                $document->addField(Field::text('texte', 'billou'));
            // Add your document to the index
                $index->addDocument($document);
                $index->commit();






    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you don't have access to the container inside your listener class by default. However, don't just extend your class from `Controller` (which does have access to the container) or inject the entire container. Instead, inject only the services you need into it:

`config.yml:`

```
services:
  searchindexer.listener:
    class: ripr\WfBundle\Listener\SearchIndexer
    arguments:
      luceneSearch: "@ivory_lucene_search"
    tags:
      - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

`SearchIndexer.php:`

```
class SearchIndexer
{
    protected $luceneSearch;

    public function __constructor($luceneSearch)
    {
        $this->luceneSearch = $luceneSearch;
    }

    // ...
```

Then, anywhere you need to use the lucene search inside the listener, you can simply call `$this->luceneSearch`.

Comment: I did found yesterday a crappy solution to get me out of this problem.
Your comment is #1 really helpful to show the right way to do it and #2 taught me the tremendous interest of Dependency Injection. Thanks